# I am trying to make a spreadsheet on Excel that will work out the average of an input in the same cell

Tags: excel, average

Hi i have a spreadsheet to calculate the averages of my players in Fifa game to game. I need a to be able to input a number to a cell and it will calculate the average of that input and the past inputs in that cell.

Comment: I wonder why you can't input values in different cells in same column. Then problem is trivial. In yuur case you need VBA script, I dont think standard spreadsheet function can allow that.

Comment: So... every time someone enters something in that cell, your sheet needs to save that value somewhere else and build a list from it? This sounds like you need VBA to grab the value of the cell, every time it's changed, and append it to a list in a hidden sheet so you can grab an average of everything grabbed up to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid VBA, you can achieve this using circular references. The following solution works with the following scenario:

1. You're putting the data in cell A2 (you can change this)
2. You're never putting in a value of 0
3. You're never putting in the same value twice in a row
4. The average will be displayed in B2 (you can change this)
5. You only need to store 20 values (you can extend this)
6. The history is stored in C2:C21 (you can extend this)

(If you *are* putting in the same value twice in row, you can't even achieve this using VBA easily without also adding a button that needs to be pressed manually every time, because VBA needs to see a change in value to know when it's been updated.)

To set this up, follow these steps:

1. Ensure cell A2 is empty before you start
2. Go to File > Options > Formulas and put a tick against Enable Iterative Calculation at the top right (this allows circular references)
3. Put this formula into B2: `=AVERAGEIF(C2:C21,">0")`
4. Put a heading into C1, such as "History"
5. Put this formula into C2: `=IF($A$2=0,0,IF(AND(C2=0,C1<>0,C1<>$A$2),$A$2,C2))`
6. Fill the formula down to C21

You can now start entering values into A2 and each new value will be added to the list automatically.

To reset the list, put 0 into A2

[image: Example]